# Percorrer lista 2D em Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Possuo o código abaixo e desejo percorrer e exibir item por item dessa lista. Porém, não consigo fazer isso, pois é exibida a lista inteira.
Peço a ajuda de vocês.

```
lista = [[10,20,30,40],[50,60,70,80]]
i = 0
for i in range(2):
    print (lista[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode exibir todos os itens de uma sublista em uma só linha, ou seja, utilizar uma linha para exibir todos os itens de uma sublista. Para isso você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
lista = [[10, 20, 30, 40], [50, 60, 70, 80]]

cont = 0
for sublista in lista:
    cont += 1
    print(f'\033[32mOs elementos da {cont}ª sublista são: ')
    for item in sublista:
        print(item, end='')
        print(', ' if item < sublista[-1] else '.', end='')
    print()
```

Veja o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/bhtogphh-solkarped).

Answer (score 3):

Ciclo for dentro do outro (nested):

```
for sublista in lista:
    for item in sublista:
        print item
```

Ou se não precisares de fazer nada às sublistas podes logo fazer a lista *flat*:

```
 print '\n'.join(str(item) for sub in lista for item in sub)
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Danilo, se a resposta te ajudou, considere [marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: de nada @Danilo. Ainda bem que ajudei

Comment: Certamente, farei isso. Porém informa que só posso fazer isso após 10 minutos. Por isso não apareceu ainda para você.

Comment: Obgado @LuizVieira (: